# Extend np.array() by dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an original array

```
w = np.ones([2, 4, 2, 3])
```

And I am operating on the subset `[:, 2, :, 1]`. On this subset, I have an array that tells me whether `w` should be updated.

```
update = array([[False,  True], [False,  True]])
```

Basically, `update[0, 1] == True` implies that `w[0, 2, 1, 1]` should be increased: The first (0) dimension corresponds to the 0 dimension in `w`, the second dimension corresponds to dimension 2 in `w`. Dimensions 1 and 3 are fixed to be `(2, 1)` (since that's the subset I was operating on).

Now, I would like to affect `w` on the dimensions implied by `update`. Basically, I'm looking for `index`, such that when doing

```
w[index] = 0
```

I'm setting to 0 elements `[0, 2, 1, 1]`, and `[1, 2, 1, 1]`.

If `w` was just my `2x2` array, I could do that by `w[update] = 0`, but I have to take into account the additional dimensions that are inbetween. How would I do that cleanly?

#### More complicated setup

Now, instead of working on the simple subset `[:, 2, :, 1]`, I am working on something more complicated.

I have an array called secondDim

```
secondDim = np.array([2, 3])
```

It contains the second dimension as a function of the first dimension. That is, when the first dimension is equal to 0, I slice the second dimension on 2. When the first dimension is  equal to 1, I slice the second dimension on 3.

Now, I'm looking for `index`, such that when I set

```
w[index] = 0
```

I set to 0 elements `[0, secondDim[0], 1, 1]` and `[1, secondDim[1], 1, 1]` - i.e. `[0, 2, 1, 1]` and `[1, 3, 1, 1]`.

Comment: I'm happy to change the title, I don't really know how to call properly what I'm trying to do, which also made the google search for pre-existing questions much more difficult.

Comment: How about `w[:,2,:,1][update] = 0`?

Comment: @Divakar That works! I tried something similar in a more complicated setting before and I was under the impression that serial indexing would give you a copy instead of a view, but it's working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part - 1**

Simply `w[:,2,:,1][update] = 0` works.

**Part - 2**

One approach would be with storing the row, col indices from the `mask` and using those for `subscripted-indexing` -

```
r,c = np.where(update)
a[r,secondDim,c,1] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [213]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,[2, 4, 2, 3])

In [222]: secondDim
Out[222]: array([2, 3])

In [216]: update   # For first and third dims
Out[216]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [214]: a[0, 2, 1, 1]
Out[214]: 85

In [215]: a[1, 3, 1, 1]
Out[215]: 47

In [217]: r,c = np.where(update)

In [218]: a[r,secondDim,c,1] # access those elems
Out[218]: array([85, 47])

In [219]: a[r,secondDim,c,1] = 0 # assign 0s

In [220]: a[0, 2, 1, 1] # verify
Out[220]: 0

In [221]: a[1, 3, 1, 1] # verify
Out[221]: 0
```

We can employ this method for `part-1` too -

```
w[r,2,c,1] = 0
```